# Are these expressions the same in C programming?

Tags: c

I am not sure if these expression means the same thing or not..

```
(*x)++;
*x = *x + 1;
*x += 1;
```

Are they measn increment pointer?

Comment: These are statements, not expressions.  The statements are the same but the expressions are not

Answer (score 2):

In all three statements, `*x` means the object that `x` points to.

This statement:

> `(*x)++;`

says to add one to `*x`. It is the same as `*x += 1;`, discussed below.

This statement:

> `*x = *x + 1;`

says to get the value of `*x`, add one to it, and store the result in `*x`.

For normal objects `x` and `*x`, this is the same as adding one to `*x`. However if `x` is volatile, that tells the compiler `x` may be different each time it is used (because something outside the regular program may be changing it) and also that reading `x` is important (because reading it may affect something outside the regular program).

If `x` is volatile, then the compiler has to get the value of `x` separately for the `*x` on the left side of the `=` and the `*x` on the right side. So this statement could end up changing a different object than the one it reads from.

If `*x` has an atomic type, then this statement has two separate accesses to `*x`, one to read it and one to write it. It is possible for other operations on `*x` to occur between this read and this write. Contrast this with `*x += 1;` below.

(Volatile and atomic types are rare in most programs. Although they are important and indeed are in frequent use, their uses are often restricted to special parts of programs and operating systems, so normal code does not have to deal with them.)

> `*x += 1;`

This adds one to `*x`. Additionally, if `*x` has an atomic type, then the read and the write of `*x` are bound together in a way formally defined in the C standard. Other atomic operations on `*x` cannot occur between the read and the write.

This statement uses `x` only once, so its behavior will not be affected by whether `x` is volatile or not (except that, if `x` is volatile, its value must actually be read rather than combined with uses of `x` in other statements by compiler optimization).

Answer (score -2):

---

Yes all the three statements means the same .
(*x)++; which means increment value pointed by x

*x = *x + 1; this is read by compiler as
-> (value pointed by x) + 1

*x += 1; which is nothing but shorthand notation of  *x = *x + 1;

---

```
enter code here
int a = 10 ;
int *x = &a;

printf("(*x)++ value  %d ",(*x)++);
*x = *x + 1;
printf("*x = *x + 1 value  %d ",*x);
*x += 1;
printf("*x += 1 value  %d ",*x);
```

Comment: These statements do not mean the same thing if `*x` has an atomic type or `x` is volatile.